# Online users in firebase chat app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I am building a chatapp using firebase database. I need to show online users, how can I do that?
I already tried this

```
connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {

            } else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
    });
```

But I don't know how to use it, please help me.

Comment: I suggest you to read [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html), it is about building a presence system using firebase. It is really interesting

Comment: In addition to that (highly recommended) blog posts, there a section in the Firebase documentation that covers this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to create a new category in your Firebase database called `onlineUsers`. Every time a user is connecting to your app, add him to this newly created category. Then you can query on that category to see the exact number of users like this:

```
int numberOfUsers = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();.
```

If you need to display a green dot for online members in a list of members, then the way in which you need to add these users in this new node, is to have the id as it's key and the value as a boolean. The default boolean value must be `false`, which means that the user is not logged in. Your new node should look like this:

```
userId1: true
userId2: false
userId3: true
```

Every time a user signs in, change the value of that user from `false` to `true`. To display them, just query your database accordingly to see which users have the value of `true`.

Comment: Not like that, for example, I need to display a green dot for online members in a list of members.

Comment: Hi, I have struck with showing online and offline users in my chat app. If we use the above code, How can manage things like one user are open the app and after one minute he is close the app. In this situation how can we get online and offline users list?

Comment: @Deepak Please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so me and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 0):

If clients have a server to work up against, 
each client connection is reported to the server, which increments a coutner.
And for such increment server is notifying (e.g. using Firebase data notification message) all clients.

This is how all clients will have indication about how many are conencted at any given time.

(When a new user is logged in, server is sending data about current number of connections)